# Custom cliping region Windows Mobile 6.x

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

We can specify ClipRectangle property on the PaintEventArgs object to get rectangular clipping. Is there a way to do custom shaped clipping. I want to clip the control to a round rect with different corner radiuses.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [description of the CLIPOBJ structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee489903%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) for Windows CE:

> The region described by CLIPOBJ can be enumerated as a series of
>   rectangles.

Which means that clipping is *restricted* to a sequence of rectangular regions. Windows Mobile 6.X are based on Windows CE, so I think it is safe to assume that the same restrictions applies.

A possible workaround would be to use GDI+ through [OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/) as mentioned [here](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2008/11/21/gdi-am-compactframework/), and [here](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/10/31/using-gdi-on-windows-mobile.aspx). You could use the class `OpenNETCF.GDIPlus.GraphicsPath` with combination of calls to the methods `AddLine`, `AddArc` and `AddRectangle` to achieve the same goal.